# From a given number, determine three close numbers whose product is the original number

Tags: algorithm, math, language-agnostic, numbers

I have a number `n`, and I want to find three numbers whose product is `n` but are as close to each other as possible. That is, if `n = 12` then I'd like to get 3, 2, 2 as a result, as opposed to 6, 1, 2.

Another way to think of it is that if `n` is the volume of a cuboid then I want to find the lengths of the sides so as to make the cuboid as much like a cube as possible (that is, the lengths as similar as possible). These numbers must be integers.

I know there is unlikely to be a perfect solution to this, and I'm happy to use something which gives a good answer most of the time, but I just can't think where to go with coming up with this algorithm. Any ideas?

Comment: What would be the metric for how close together the three numbers are?

Comment: How large is your typical `n`?

Comment: @Anders - Fairly small, probably between 1 and 50. @Phonon - Good question! I'm not really sure. I'm really just looking for some sort of solution that can give me a fairly good answer (as in the numbers are fairly close together) as much as possible. For some `n` the numbers can be very close, but for others they'll probably have to be a fair distance apart. I guess I'm just looking for something that does it roughly...

Comment: I'd think an efficient search would start by setting each value to the cube root of N, then searching outward from there.

Comment: If n is between 1 and 50, why not just precompute the results?

Comment: You need to clearly define what you mean by "as close as possible". Come up with an equation and then pick your favorite optimization method.

Comment: Clearly (IMHO), "as close as possible" means `max(a, b, c) - min(a, b, c)` is closer to zero than any other solution.

Comment: Write a function which states how good a solution is and do brute-force using the prime factorization of n. For such small n, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Before applying any algorithm I think you should divide out the largest possible cube first. Use some algorithm, like the ones below. And then at the end, multiply your three factors by the cube root of that cube. Eg. to solve for 120, pull out 8 first, leaving 15. Much easier. Now use your method on 15 and then multiply each of the factors by 2.

Comment: @user207442: Consider 576.  Your method would give 4, 12, 12 while the best answer is 8, 8, 9.

Comment: @user207442: Smallest counter-example is 24, your solution is (2,2,6), but (2,3,4) is better. For 120 you get (2,6,10) whereas (4,5,6) is better. Numbers which are chosen to be as close together as possible tend not to have common factors unless they're equal :-)

Comment: Too greedy too early. My bad :-)

Comment: @robintw Don't you mean to say: "Another way to think of it is that if `n` is the volume of a cuboid"...

Comment: Would I be right in thinking this would be a good problem to solve with branch-and-bound?

Comment: @robintw: I just noticed that you hadn't mentioned that your 3 numbers should be integers (although I, along with every one else, assumed that they were). Do they have to be integers?

Comment: @yoda - Yes they do. I'll update it to make that explicit

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's my first algorithm sketch, granted that `n` is relatively small:

- Compute the [prime factors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_factor) of `n`.
- Pick out the three largest and assign them to `f1`, `f2`, `f3`. If there are less than three factors, assign `1`.
- Loop over remaining factors *in decreasing order*, multiply them into the currently smallest partition.

---

*Edit*

Let's take `n=60`.

Its prime factors are `5 3 2 2`.

Set `f1=5`, `f2=3` and `f3=2`.

The remaining `2` is multiplied to `f3`, because it is the smallest.

We end up with `5 * 4 * 3 = 60`.

---

*Edit*

This algorithm will not find optimum, notice [btillys](https://stackoverflow.com/users/585411/btilly) comment:

> Consider 17550 = 2 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 5 * 5
>   * 13. Your algorithm would give 15, 30, 39 when the best is 25, 26, 27.

---

*Edit*

Ok, here's my second algorithm sketch with a slightly better heuristic:

- Set the list `L` to the [prime factors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_factor) of `n`.
- Set `r` to the [cube root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_root) of `n`.
- Create the set of three factors `F`, initially set to `1`.
- Iterate over the prime factors in descending order:

  - Try to multiply the current factor `L[i]` with each of the factors in descending order.

    - If the result is less than `r`, perform the multiplication and move on to the next 
      prime factor.
    - If not, try the next `F`. If out of `F`s, multiply with the smallest one.

This will work for the case of `17550`:

```
n=17550
L=13,5,5,3,3,3,2
r=25.98

F = { 1, 1, 1 }
```

**Iteration 1:**

- `F[0] * 13` is less than `r`, set `F` to `{13,1,1}`.

**Iteration 2:**

- `F[0] * 5 = 65` is greated than `r`.
- `F[1] * 5 = 5` is less than `r`, set `F` to `{13,5,1}`.

**Iteration 3:**

- `F[0] * 5 = 65` is greated than `r`.
- `F[1] * 5 = 25` is less than `r`, set `F` to `{13,25,1}`.

**Iteration 4:**

- `F[0] * 3 = 39` is greated than `r`.
- `F[1] * 3 = 75` is greated than `r`.
- `F[2] * 3 = 3` is less than `r`, set `F` to `{13,25,3}`.

**Iteration 5:**

- `F[0] * 3 = 39` is greated than `r`.
- `F[1] * 3 = 75` is greated than `r`.
- `F[2] * 3 = 9` is less than `r`, set `F` to `{13,25,9}`.

**Iteration 6:**

- `F[0] * 3 = 39` is greated than `r`.
- `F[1] * 3 = 75` is greated than `r`.
- `F[2] * 3 = 27` is greater than `r`, but it is the smallest F we can get. Set `F` to `{13,25,27}`.

**Iteration 7:**

- `F[0] * 2 = 26` is greated than `r`, but it is the smallest F we can get. Set `F` to `{26,25,27}`.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "the currently smallest partition" though?

Comment: I like it, although I don't think this will always give the best answer. Starting from a prime factorization is a good way to begin.

Comment: @justin: Yes, I'm not sure this is optimal either. It might be feasible to enumerate all partitions of the prime factors to find the optimal one.

Comment: @Anders - It is pretty good, though. I'm trying to find a case where it fails, and it's not that easy, as long as I "loop over the remaining factors" in decreasing order.

Comment: @Justin: Clarified the answer, of course the factors should be examined in decreasing order.

Comment: The number of partitions is only O(n^(log 3)) I think, since n has O(log n) prime factors counting duplicates. So for the tiny n <= 50 that the the questioner is talking about, it seems sensible to test any method for accuracy by comparison with brute force. And then just use either brute force or a lookup table computed by brute force...

Comment: @Anders Good start, but this solution is not likely be optimal in all cases.  Imagine `n` has 17 prime factors of widely differing magnitudes, for example.

Comment: Consider 17550 = 2 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 5 * 5 * 13.  Your algorithm would give 15, 30, 39 when the best is 25, 26, 27.

Comment: @btilly Please take a look at my algorithm. It correctly gives {25, 26, 27}.

Comment: @david-carraher: The algorithm you described does not give that result.  When I follow your instructions I get the following intermediate steps and operations in order: `1 1 1(<-13)`, `13 1 1(<-5)`, `13 5 1(<-5)`, `13 5 5(<-3)`, `15 13 5(<-3)`, `15 15 13(<-3)`, `39 15 15(<-2)`, `39 30 15`.  If you think you should come up with something else, please clarify your description.

Comment: @Anders, what does your algorithm give for numbers `68, 318, 1098`?  If I coded it right I am getting `{1, 4, 17}`, `{1, 6, 53}` and `{2, 9, 61}` when I believe `{2, 2, 17}`, `{2, 3, 53}`, and `{3, 6, 61}` are better.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Good point, thanks for the counter example. You could try to only update a factor if the result is less than the floor of the cube root?

Comment: Let me try that. ...edit...  Well, I tried that but the results seem all wrong now (`{15, 30, 39}` for 17550 for example).  Am I doing this right?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: The algorithm was just quickly sketched up, so it is very possible that it won't find the optimum in every case. It seems like it is worth examining how the cut-off on the cube root should be handled.

Comment: @Anders: +1 for your first attempt-algorithm. Simple, fast and gives optimum or near-optimum.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a purely math based approach, that returns the optimal solution and does not involve any kind of sorting. Hell, it doesn't even need the prime factors.

### Background:

1) Recall that for a polynomial

[image]

the sum and product of the roots are given by

[image]

where `x_i` are the roots.

2) Recall another elementary result from optimization theory:

[image]

i.e., given two variables such that their product is a constant, the sum is minimum when the two variables are equal to each other. The tilde variables denote the optimal values.

A corollary of this would be that if the sum of two variables whose product is constant, is a minimum, then the two variables are equal to each other.

### Reformulate the original problem:

Your question above can now be reformulated as a polynomial root-finding exercise. We'll construct a polynomial that satisfies your conditions, and the roots of that polynomial will be your answer. If you need `k` numbers that are optimal, you'll have a polynomial of degree `k`. In this case, we can talk in terms of a cubic equation

[image]

We know that:

1. `c` is the negative of the input number (assume positive)
2. `a` is an integer and negative (since factors are all positive)
3. `b` is an integer (which is the sum of the roots taken two at a time) and is positive.
4. Roots of `p` must be real (and positive, but that has already been addressed).

To solve the problem, we simply need to maximize `a` subject to the above set of conditions. The only part not explicitly known right now, is condition 4, which we can easily enforce using the [discriminant of the polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant).

For a cubic polynomial `p`, the discriminant is

[image]

and `p` has real and distinct roots if `∆>0` and real and coincident (either two or all three) if `∆=0`. So, constraint 4 now reads `∆>=0`. This is now simple and easy to program.

### Solution in Mathematica

Here's a solution in Mathematica that implements this.

[image]

And here's a test on some of the numbers used in other answers/comments.

[image]

The column on the left is the list and the corresponding row in the column on the right gives the optimal solution.

#### NOTE:

> I just noticed that OP never mentioned that the 3 numbers needed to be integers although everyone (including myself until now) assumed that they were (probably because of his first example). Re-reading the question, and going by the cube example, it doesn't seem like OP was fixated on integers.
>
> This is an important point which will decide which class of algorithms to pursue and needs to be defined. If they need not be integers, there are several polynomial based solutions that can be provided, one of which is mine (after relaxing the integer constraint). If they should be integers, then perhaps an approach using branch-n-bound/branch-n-cut/cutting plane might be more appropriate.

*The following was written assuming the OP meant the three numbers to be integers.*

The way I've implemented it right now, it can give a non-integer solution in certain cases.

[image]

The reason this gives non-integer solutions for `x` is because I had only maximized `a`, when actually, `b` also needs to be minimum (not only that, but also because I haven't placed a constraint on the `x_i` being integers. It is possible to use the *integer root theorem*, which would involve finding the prime factors, but makes things more complicated.)

**Mathematica code in text**

```
Clear[poly, disc, f]
poly = x^3 + a x^2 + b x + c;
disc = Discriminant[poly, x];
f[n_Integer] := 
 Module[{p, \[CapitalDelta] = disc /. c -> -n}, 
  p = poly /. 
     Maximize[{a, \[CapitalDelta] >= 0, 
        b > 0 && a < 0 && {a, b} \[Element] Integers}, {a, b}][[
      2]] /. c -> -n;
  Solve[p == 0]
  ]
```

Comment: I'm not really convinced that this is `O(1)`. Can you try it with `c=2*3*5*7*...*997` or `c=2*3*5*7*...*999983` and tell us how fast it was done?

Comment: @ypercube: You're right, it's not `O(1)`. I had only randomly checked for numbers till `~10^30`, and it ran pretty fine (~0.01 s). It runs _lot_ slower for the first number you suggested, which is `~10^500` (>1 min, and I aborted). I'm not even trying the second. Thanks for pointing that out, and I've edited my post to remove those claims. I guess what I was trying to say that it's a lot lot faster than sorting tuples, but in my over zealousness, I went overboard :)

Comment: Running in a fraction of a second for numbers up to 10^30 is pretty good anyway. Does it check all numbers a and b with `0<b<c` and `-c<a<0` when trying to maximize? I'm not sure I understand fully the Mathematica code.

Comment: @ypercube: It need not be `0<b<c` or `-c<a<0`; for e.g. consider `n=2`. The three optimal numbers are `1,1,2`, for which `a=-4`, `b=5`, `c=2`. The central portion of the code is simply this: _Maximize `a`, such that `a` is a negative integer, `b` is a positive integer and the discriminant `∆` is non-negative. Once `a` and `b` are found, substitute in the original polynomial and find its roots_.

Comment: yoda, when you post a picture of Mathematica code, please also include the code itself, at least in the "enter image description here" box.

Comment: @ypercube: The problem is NP hard, so I don't think a simple polynomial solution can be found that will work for _every_ `n`.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard: Done. I found that it doesn't work if you enter in the "enter image description" box, as the mma brackets interfere.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a clever way to find the tightest triplet, as Anders Lindahl is pursuing, but I will focus on a more basic approach.

If I generate *all* triplets, then I can filter them afterward however I want, so I will start there.  The best way I know to generate these uses recursion:

---

```
f[n_, 1] := {{n}}

f[n_, k_] := Join @@
    Table[
      {q, ##} & @@@ Select[f[n/q, k - 1], #[[1]] >= q &],
      {q, #[[2 ;; ⌈ Length@#/k ⌉ ]] & @ Divisors @ n}
    ]
```

This function `f` takes two integer arguments, the number to factor `n`, and the number of factors to produce `k`.

The section `#[[2 ;; ⌈ Length@#/k ⌉ ]] & @ Divisors @ n` uses `Divisors` to produce a list of all divisors of `n` (including `1`), and then takes from these from the second (to drop the `1`) to the Ceiling of the number of divisors divided by `k`.

For example, for `{n = 240, k = 3}` the output is `{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8}`

The `Table` command iterates over this list while accumulating results, assigning each element to `q`.

The body of the `Table` is `Select[f[n/q, k - 1], #[[1]] >= q &]`.  This calls `f` recursively, and then selects from the result all lists that begin with a number `>= q`.

`{q, ##} & @@@` (also in the body) then "prepends" `q` to each of these selected lists.

Finally, `Join @@` merges the lists of these selected lists that are produced by each loop of `Table`.

---

The result is all of the integer factors of `n` into `k` parts, in lexicographical order.  Example:

```
In[]:= f[240, 3]

Out[]= {{2, 2, 60}, {2, 3, 40}, {2, 4, 30}, {2, 5, 24}, {2, 6, 20},
        {2, 8, 15}, {2, 10, 12}, {3, 4, 20}, {3, 5, 16}, {3, 8, 10},
        {4, 4, 15}, {4, 5, 12}, {4, 6, 10}, {5, 6, 8}}
```

---

With the output of the function/algorithm given above, one can then test triplets for quality however desired.

Notice that because of the ordering the last triplet in the output is the one with the greatest minimum factor.  This will usually be the most "cubic" of the results, but occasionally it is not.

If the true optimum must be found, it makes sense to test starting from the right side of the list, abandoning the search if a better result is not found quickly, as the quality of the results decrease as you move left.

---

Obviously this method relies upon a fast `Divisors` function, but I presume that this is either a standard library function, or you can find a good implementation here on StackOverflow.  With that in place, this should be quite fast.  The code above finds all triplets for n from 1 to 10,000 in 1.26 seconds on my machine.

Comment: W +1 Your approach is a *very, very* efficient means of arriving at the triplets of divisors. But you still need to decide somehow which triplet is most cube-like.  If we combine your approach with the shortest space diagonal criterion I proposed, we'd have a heck of a quick complete solution to the challenge, don't you think?

Comment: @David I hope so. :-)  By the way, why is the diagonal superior to the ratio of largest to smallest factor?

Comment: (at long last...) My preference is more sentimental than rational. Empirically, they tend to give the same solution.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**
Here's a shorter explanation using more efficient code, [KSetPartitions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Combinatorica/ref/KSetPartitions.html) simplifies things considerably.  So did some suggestions from Mr.W. The overall logic remains the same.

Assuming there a at least 3 prime factors of *n*,

1. Find the list of triplet `KSetPartitions` for the prime factors of *n*.
2. Multiply each of the elements (prime factors) within each subset to produce all possible combinations for three divisors of *n* (when multiplied they yield *n*). You can think of the divisors as the length, width and height of an orthogonal parallelepiped.
3. The parallelepiped closest to a cube will have the shortest space diagonal.  Sum the squares of the three divisors for each case and pick the smallest.

---

Here's the code in Mathematica:

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
g[n_] := Module[{factors = Join @@ ConstantArray @@@ FactorInteger[n]},
  Sort[Union[Sort /@ Apply[Times, Union[Sort /@ 
      KSetPartitions[factors, 3]], {2}]] 
      /. {a_Integer, b_Integer, c_Integer} :>  
           {Total[Power[{a, b, c}, 2]], {a, b, c}}][[1, 2]]]
```

---

It can handle fairly large numbers, but slows down considerably as the number of factors of n grows.  The examples below show timings for 240, 2400, ...24000000.
This could be sped up in principle by taking into account cases where a prime factor appears more than once in a divisor. I don't have the know-how to do it yet.

```
In[28]:= g[240]

Out[28]= {5, 6, 8}

In[27]:= t = Table[Timing[g[24*10^n]][[1]], {n, 6}]

Out[27]= {0.001868, 0.012734, 0.102968, 1.02469, 10.4816, 105.444}
```

Comment: David, I gave this a vote because I believe it works, but unfortunately it "blows up" pretty quickly.  This can be done faster, and without eating all my RAM.  Give me a few minutes to get my notes together.

Comment: @Mr. W  Any help is appreciated. I'm uncharacteristically optimistic about the logic of the approach, even though it's admittedly a bit greedy. It'll be interesting to hear what sort of efficiency improvements you come up with. You always do.

Comment: David, that is kind of you.  I will post a solution sooner or later, but I got busy with a few things.  First, I would like to see if Anders Lindahl has a response to my question/critique of his method, because I think his may be the fastest, if it can be made to work correctly (or already is, and I am coding it wrong).

Comment: In the mean time, let me toss out a few things that I think can be improved in your code (I'll worry about method later).  (1) `Flatten[FactorInteger[n] /. {a_Integer, b_Integer} :> Table[a, {b}]]` should be replaced with `Join @@ ConstantArray @@@ FactorInteger@n` (2) I think `Sqrt` is superfluous (3) it is better to square all numbers at once since `Power` is `Listable` and add with `Total` than to process each triple with a rule `{a_, b_, c_} :> ...` (4) SortBy should be faster than the decorate-and-sort method you are using

Comment: (5) your decorate-and-sort is extra slow because you are using a custom sort function; put the "sorting" element first in each sublist, and use the default `Sort` instead. (6) Generating all set partitions is highly inefficient.  Well, that should be enough attacking your code I think. :o)

Comment: Thanks so much. `Sqrt` is indeed superfluous: it's a vestige of an earlier comparison between the space diagonals.  There are also redundancies in the solutions that can be eliminated earlier through `Sort` and `Union`.  On the other hand, I think it's important to generate all set partitions before paring them down. This is not really as source of inefficiency.

Comment: Mr. W. Actually, my tests show that `SetPartitions` is very greedy. `KSetPartitions` can be used to generate blocks of 3. Will be MUCH faster.

Comment: That is much improved.  `KSetPartitions` is still not optimal, because of the repeats (which you strip out with Union).  This is not any faster, but it is a little cleaner:  `g2[n_] := 
 Module[{factors = Join @@ ConstantArray @@@ FactorInteger[n]},
  SortBy[
    Union[
     Sort /@ Apply[Times, 
       Union[Sort /@ KSetPartitions[factors, 3]], {2}]],
    Total[#^2] &
    ][[1]]
  ]`

Comment: Mr. W. Yeh, I cut and pasted from the wrong place in my file. Fixed it.

Comment: David, have you considered my code in the comment above?  I think `SortBy[ ... , Total[#^2] & ]` is cleaner.

Comment: Mr.Wizard I've been busy but plan to get to it shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, one should recognize this as a variation of a well known **NP-complete** problem.

- Compute the prime factors of `n`.
- Compute the logarithms of these factors
- The problem translates as partitioning these logs into three sums that are as close as possible.
- This problem is known as a variation of the **[Bin Packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem)** problem, known as **[Multiprocessor scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiprocessor_scheduling)**

Given the fact that the Multiprocessor scheduling problem is NP-complete, it's no wonder that it's hard to find an algorithm that does not search the whole problem space and finds the optimum solution.

But I guess there are already several algorithms that deal with either Bin-Packing or Multiprocessor-Scheduling and find near-optimum solutions in efficient manner.

Another related problem (generalization) is the **[Job shop scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling)**. See the wikipedia description with many links to known algorithms.

---

What wikipedia describes as ***(the often-used LPT-Algorithm (Longest Processing Time)*** is exactly what Anders Lindahl came up with first.

Comment: And what do you propose to do with the logarithms of the prime factors?

Comment: Are you claiming this problem is NP-complete?  I give you an instance of of a Bin Packing problem.  I also let you call my oracle cubic product minimizer that solves any instance of a cubic minimizer problem in polynomial time.  How do you solve the bin packing problem in polynomial time?